# Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView after changing sqlcipher version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, sqlcipher, xwalkview

The android app I am working on is a Cordova one.
I am getting the following error when I start the app.
https://pastebin.com/jzX9AqEX

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XWalkView xWalkWebView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
        XWalkCookieManager mCookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
        mCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        mCookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);

    }
}
```

I am getting the error at `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Here is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
    android:id="@+id/xwalkWebView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I wasn't getting this error until I updated sqlcipher to 3.5.7
Here is my xwalkview version : org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you likely just have to read the stacktrace completely: `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Please have your activity extend XWalkActivity for shared mode`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko How do I extend that? Also the app crashes when I open it

Comment: if you don't know how to extend something, then you likely missing Java basics

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So its basic Java class extension? I thought I had to do something in the xml

Comment: no, the error says that you need to extend your `MainActivity` from `XWalkActivity`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko That wont work because I need CordovaActivity and its methods. Sorry, I am new to Android

Comment: well, probably then it is not compatible with cordova then

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Hmm... okay. thanks for your help